# How to see verbose error logs in the Rails console when running in production?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

One of the biggest challenges I have with my Ruby on Rails application is that troubleshooting production bugs can become extremely painful due to the lack of information in the logs.

```
I, [2021-01-08T14:42:44.834966 #223]  INFO -- : [1b0730a0-21e4-476f-92a6-6b4d86e98010] undefined method `id' for nil:NilClass
I, [2021-01-08T14:42:44.865441 #223]  INFO -- : [1b0730a0-21e4-476f-92a6-6b4d86e98010] No template found for SubscriptionPaymentController#payment_webhook, rendering head :no_content
I, [2021-01-08T14:42:44.865759 #223]  INFO -- : [1b0730a0-21e4-476f-92a6-6b4d86e98010] Completed 204 No Content in 887ms (ActiveRecord: 7.3ms)
```

For example, the above code shows an error in production, but there's no verbose information on how to fix it. In dev, I believe it would show the specific line number of the code where the error occurred.

Since this `production.log` file can't be shown to the user in the UI anywhere, is there any way I could just simply turn on "more" verbose logging so that I can easier figure out where bugs occur in production?

Comment: The default log level is already the highest one (debug) since Rails 4.2.

Comment: Do you somehow have some sort of general error catcher in the code that catches everything and than manually logs the error? The `undefined method error` in your example that is only printed as `INFO` level points to something like this being the case

Answer (score 1):

In your `production.rb` file you can change `config.log_level` property to `debug`, like this  `config.log_level = :debug`. This is the lowest level available. ([more info on log levels](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/debugging_rails_applications.html#log-levels))

**HOWEVER** this is only recommended to be done in production when you are trying to fix something, but then it should be reverted to a higher level otherwise you risk filling the disk space very fast.

Comment: Unfortunately it looks like this is already set to debug. No luck.